# curve extrusion doesn't work anymore

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, bezier-curves, extrude

Not sure what I've done, but I am unable to undo it. When I extrude the curve, it summons a white dot instead of adding a joint curve.

I am not sure where I did wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have accidentally pressed <kbd>H</kbd> (hide), it has hidden the last extrusion, and when you try to do a new extrusion, as one already exists, it just creates a single vertex. So try to press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.